# Memory leak in ATL 8 thunk code?

Tags: visual-c++, atl

I'm using ATL 8 and am on a machine with DEP. Visual Leak Detector is reporting a memory leak that stems from a `HeapAlloc` call in `atlthunk.cpp`, specifically this line of code:

```
atlThunkPool = 
    (PSLIST_HEADER)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(SLIST_HEADER));
```

And sure enough, I looked for hours but could not find a corresponding HeapFree anywhere.  Also, there is a call to `VirtualAlloc` in the same file, i.e.

```
thunkPage = (PATL_THUNK_ENTRY)VirtualAlloc(NULL, 
    PAGE_SIZE, 
    MEM_COMMIT, 
    PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

And there isn't a corresponding `VirtualFree` (except under certain conditions). Am I going crazy or is this a bug in ATL?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a leak, no freeing in Visual Studio 2010 ATL too. It is perhaps assumed that you would only create a code thunk once and it won't drain memory a lot if you don't free it (still a problem with a DLL loaded and unloaded). I don't see code in VS2010 ATL where thunk pool is freed.

Comment: Thanks for looking at that, true maybe it is due to certain assumptions. Is there a place where I can submit this as a bug to Microsoft?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio or Microsoft Support

Comment: Why not share a link http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/700042/vs-2010-atl-memory-leak so that it could be voted for?

Comment: Oh good idea thanks for the vote! Anyone else interested please also vote

Comment: BTW this ATL source code file (atlthunk.cpp) is not present on post VS 2010 versions, so it's hard to tell whether the issue was fixed or not.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the information